# Insufficient suitable allocatable extents error when performing RAID takeover

Tags: lvm, software-raid

To improve performance while still keeping redundancy, I am trying to convert the root file system of a NAS from a RAID 5 logical volume to a RAID 10 logical volume, while keeping the same number of disks used.

In [this](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/lvm2/lvmraid.7.en#RAID_TAKEOVER) section of the `lvmraid` man page, it suggests converting RAID 10 and RAID 5 is possible with an indirect conversion.

> The following takeover conversions are currently possible:
>
> ...
>
> - between striped/raid0 and raid5.
>
> ...
>
> - between striped/raid0 and raid10.

But when running the appropriate `lvconvert` command (on a similar `test` LV), repeatedly as prompted to perform the intermediate conversions, I get this error in the last step when finally converting from RAID 0 to RAID 10:

```
root@nas:~# lvcreate --type raid5 -i 3 -n test -L 100M vg
  Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
  Rounding size 100.00 MiB (25 extents) up to stripe boundary size 108.00 MiB (27 extents).
  Logical volume "test" created.

root@nas:~# lvconvert vg/test --type raid10 -m 1 -i 2
  Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
  Replaced LV type raid10 (same as raid10_near) with possible type raid5_n.
  Repeat this command to convert to raid10 after an interim conversion has finished.
  Converting raid5 (same as raid5_ls) LV vg/test to raid5_n.
Are you sure you want to convert raid5 LV vg/test? [y/n]: y
  Logical volume vg/test successfully converted.

root@nas:~# lvconvert vg/test --type raid10 -m 1 -i 2
  Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
  Replaced LV type raid10 (same as raid10_near) with possible type raid0_meta.
  Repeat this command to convert to raid10 after an interim conversion has finished.
Are you sure you want to convert raid5_n LV vg/test to raid0_meta type? [y/n]: y
  Logical volume vg/test successfully converted.

root@nas:~# lvconvert vg/test --type raid10 -m 1 -i 2
  Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
Are you sure you want to convert raid0_meta LV vg/test to raid10 type? [y/n]: y
  Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume : 30 more required

root@nas:~#
```

Even when freeing up physical extents and reducing the LV size, I get the same error. All the physical volumes are allocatable.

Here is the `vgdisplay` output:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        4
  Metadata Sequence No  333
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                4
  Act PV                4
  VG Size               <3.64 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              953864
  Alloc PE / Size       943654 / <3.60 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       10210 / 39.88 GiB
  VG UUID               PF08Ce-xvsS-7KsA-0Vw6-zkXR-jyUf-ocDWDW
```

How do I resolve this error? I would like to use the same PEs for the converted LV, shrinking the file system as necessary.

Comment: [one previous answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726495/117549), in case it helps the post here any.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of this description, consider *disk* to mean a disk, partition or other logical container. Each *disk* is considered to be the same size, holding a *unit* of storage (1GB, 1TB, whatever; it doesn't matter).

- RAID 5 uses three disks for two units of useful storage
- RAID 0 uses two disks for two units of useful storage
- RAID 10 uses two disks for one unit of useful storage; typically RAID 10 can be considered as RAID 1 on top of RAID 0 (or v.v.) so you would use four disks for two units of useful storage

Also

- When you convert from RAID 5 to RAID 0 you have one unit of storage left over (i.e. one disk is spare)
- When you convert from RAID 0 to RAID 10 you need an additional unit of storage for each unit that you're converting (i.e. two extra disks on top of the two you're currently using)

Consequence: you started with three disks so you're one disk short.

One option might be to see if you can reduce your RAID 0 array down from using two disks to one, but this presupposes your original RAID 5 array is only half full. The other option is to obtain a fourth disk.